# JSON schema draft-04: extending for specific "enum" value

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm trying to extend JSON schema, which defines an enum:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "objType": {
      "enum": [ "A", "B" ]
    },
    "baseType": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "category": { "$ref": "#/definitions/objType" }
      }
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "A": {
      "allOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/baseType" },
        /* how to restrict inherited `category' to "A"? */
        { /* properties specific to A */ }
      ]
    },
    "B": {
      "allOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/baseType" },
        /* how to restrict inherited `category' to "B"? */
        { /* properties specific to B */ }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how restrict inherited enum property to specific value. For example:

```
// passes validation
{
  "category": "A",
  "prop_A": "blah A"
}

// fails because `prop_A' is not valid property for category "B"
{
  "category": "B",
  "prop_A":  "blah A"
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

JSON Schema is a constraint system rather than an object oriented system, so "inheritance" as a concept doesn't fit very well.  See https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-org.github.io/issues/148 for more information.

However, in your case, I think that the constraint system is exactly what you want.  In a constraint system, you can always add more constraints, but you can never remove them.  So restricting an enum to a subset of its "inherited" values is as simple as using `"allOf"` to add a constraint of a single-valued enum over top of the original two-valued enum.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "objType": {
      "enum": [ "A", "B" ]
    },
    "baseType": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "category": { "$ref": "#/definitions/objType" }
      }
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "A": {
      "allOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/baseType" },
        { "objType": { "enum": [ "A" ] }.
        { /* properties specific to A */ }
      ]
    },
    "B": {
      "allOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/baseType" },
        { "objType": { "enum": [ "B" ] }.
        { /* properties specific to B */ }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You just need to further constrain the enum for each type of property at the point where it is actually used.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Building a mount point schema](http://json-schema.org/example2.html) example they do this a little differently.  Each `storage` refers to one of several types of objects:

```
"properties": {
    "storage": {
        "type": "object",
        "oneOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/diskDevice" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/diskUUID" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/nfs" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/tmpfs" }
        ]
    },
```

and each of the object types includes a `type` enum with a different value.  e.g. `diskDevice` specifies `type` in this way

```
"properties": {
    "type": { "enum": [ "disk" ] },
    "device": {
        "type": "string",
        "pattern": "^/dev/[^/]+(/[^/]+)*$"
    }
```

whereas `nfs` specifies `type` this way

```
"properties": {
    "type": { "enum": [ "nfs" ] },
    "remotePath": {
        "type": "string",
        "pattern": "^(/[^/]+)+$"
    },
```

Perhaps you could consider refactoring your schema along those lines.

Comment: yes, I saw this example. If there is no choice this is what I'll do. However, it breaks enum and scatters it all over the schema while making it prone to bugs when future changes come.

Comment: Some time ago I had a similar problem in the context of a Swagger schema and came across https://gist.github.com/leedm777/5730877 but in that approach they make the restriction *The derived type MUST NOT redefine any properties defined in any of its base types* which may make it unsuitable here as I think your goal of having *`prop_A' is not valid property for category "B"* could be considered as a violation of that restriction.  I too would like to find a better way but have not yet done so.

Answer (score 0):

With Schema Draft v6 this seems to be possible:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "category": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "const": "A"
                },
                "prop_A": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "category": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "const": "B"
                },
                "prop_B": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```